# How to maintain sort order in dynamic dropdown?

Tags: jquery, json, sorting, laravel, laravel-4

I am returning a JSON response as follows to dynamically populate a dropdown list:

```
   Route::get('api/city_list', function()
   {
       $selected_state = Input::get('selected_state');

       $city_list = City::where('state_id', '=', $selected_state)
           ->orderBy('name')
           ->lists('name', 'id');

       return $city_list;
   });
```

When hitting the URL directly, the data is sorted as expected, but when processed client side, the data is sorted by ID, not city name as desired. JQuery:

```
    $.getJSON("<URL>",
        { selected_state: $('#location_state').val() },
        function(data) {
            console.log(data) // << HERE THE LOG SHOWS THE SORT BY ID NOT NAME
            var city = $('#location_city');

            city.empty();

            $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                city.append($('<option />').val(index).text(value));
            });
        }
    );
```

It's doubtless something simple I'm missing, but why is the data being resorted?  I would like to request the data and it be sorted server side and that sorting order maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you sort the data on the client side instead?

```
data.sort(function(a,b) 
{
   return a.name - b.name;
});
```

Comment: I could, but I wanted to see if there was a way to avoid double sorting.  I'd much rather preserve the server-side sorting if possible since it would create more maintainable code.

Comment: Well you can just give up on the server side sorting so you'll end up having the sort only on the client. That will also put things easier for your server.

Answer (score 0):

if you desire to re-oreder an object notation data in javascript (JSON in short) you can use a third-library to query your items. i like jLinq: http://hugoware.net/projects/jlinq

**CAUTION**: it is lightweight and intuitive but it is also efficient only to samll amounts of data (anything beyond 100,000 would slow down your performance)